# General Rules for Choosing Colors/ Patterns

Tags: website-design, interface-design, design-principles, user-experience

So I'm trying to design a dashboard and I was wondering if there were some general rules for colors to use for buttons, borders, headers, containers etc. Like what are the appropriate colors that will stick out vs. blend in and which colors work well together. If anybody could refer me to resources or tell me where I can learn these techniques that would greatly help in presenting my information easier on the user.

Comment: The only general rule is "use the colors that look good and meet the objectives of your users".

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50742/methods-for-improving-color-choice-and-combinations

Answer (score 1):

I try to stay away from conflicts with already established rules (Eg. green CTA for validating actions, red for errors / warnings). Also, don't be afraid to emulate sections that already work (eg. facebook's friends list sidebar), thus enabling your users an easier learning of your interface.

Some interesting reads:

- [Color in UI Design: A (Practical) Framework](https://medium.com/@erikdkennedy/color-in-ui-design-a-practical-framework-e18cacd97f9e#.dhwgowgqi)
- [Color contrast checks as a good habit](https://thesiteslinger.com/blog/making-color-contrast-checks-a-part-of-your-web-workflow)

Comment: I contest any statement that "facebook works" :)